# Swift screen with map and tableView (moving)

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview

I am trying to do something like this in swift.  When I use `UiTableView`, I want my tableView to go up to half a screen and still be scrollable there.  After, when I scroll down, it moves back to bottom.

[bottom example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzU28.png),
[middle example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yuWr.png)

my code:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView?
@IBOutlet var topOffsetConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
var counter: CGFloat = 0.0
var isObserverActive: Bool?
var minOffset: CGFloat?
var maxOffset: CGFloat?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("contentOffset"), name: nil, object: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.maxOffset = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)-44+20
    self.minOffset = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)/2
    self.counter = self.minOffset!
    self.isObserverActive = true
    self.topOffsetConstraint!.constant = self.counter
}

// MARK:
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "contentOffset" && self.isObserverActive == true {
        self.isObserverActive = false
        self.changeHeaderLocation(self.tableView!.contentOffset)
    }
}

func changeHeaderLocation(newLocation: CGPoint) {
    if self.counter <= self.maxOffset && self.counter >= self.minOffset {
        self.counter -= newLocation.y
        self.counter = min(max(self.counter, self.minOffset!), self.maxOffset!)
        if CLong(self.counter) != CLong(self.minOffset!) && CLong(self.counter) != CLong(self.maxOffset!) {
            self.tableView!.contentOffset = CGPointZero
        }
    }
    self.topOffsetConstraint!.constant = self.counter
    self.isObserverActive = true
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "cellID"
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)!
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(CLong(indexPath.row))"
    return cell
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Resize your images, post some code

Comment: @AdrianKrupa ok i do this :)